# PHP cURL does not work when calling multiple URLs?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to take a list of URL's from a textbox, it has 1 URL per line and each URL does a redirect, I am trying to get the URL that it redirects to.

When I run this code below on a single URL, it returns the redirected URL which is what I want...

```
function getRedirect($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch); //Some information on the fetch
    curl_close($ch);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($info);
    echo '</pre>';

}

$url = 'http://www.domain.com/go?a:aHR0cDovL2xldGl0Yml0Lm5ldC9kb3d';
getRedirect($url);
```

Now my problem is when I try to run it on multiple URL's with this code...

```
if(isset($_POST['urls'])){
    $rawUrls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);

    foreach ($rawUrls as $url) {
        getRedirect($url);
    }
}
```

When I run it on my list of URL's instead of giving me the redirected URL like my first example does correctly, it instead gives me the URL that I passed into cURL.

Can someone help me figure out why or how to fix this please?

Comment: what does `var_dump($rawUrls)` before the foreach loop shows?

Comment: @ben the var dump just shows all the URL's that I passed in like `array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(117) "http://www.url.com/go?a:aHR0cDovL2xvc3RwaWMubmV0L2ltYWdlcy9lMDM1MzgxMjNiYWU0NGUzYjM1ODk3NjFlMWFkN2Y3Ny5qcGc=
"
  [1]=>
  string(145) "http://www.url.com/go?a:aHR0cDovL3NoYXJlZmxhcmUubmV0L2Rvd25sb2FkLzgyNTYyLjhkZWQwYWQyY2U4NWEzMmJlN2E0MDZlNWY0YmYvQW44OGdlbDAzLndtdi5odG1s
"
  [2]=>
  string(61) "http://www.url.com/go?a:aHR0cDovL3VsLnRvL2s5Mjh5MHRu
" etc...etc...`

Comment: Well, if I try one of the urls in a browser it doesn't redirect either  so maybe your list of urls isn't right.. ?

Comment: the single test url does work though

Comment: Not sure if that affects anything with curl, but your vardump shows your urls have extra spacing at the end, which curl would likely think is part of the url. Maybe try `trim()` on the url `getRedirect(trim($url));`

Comment: @ben all the URL's I posted on here are made up as it is for a client's adult site.  After more testing, `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` seems to only work for 1 url regardless of how many I try to run it on

Comment: That shouldn't be the case since you init a new instance every time..

Comment: Maybe take a look at the curl_multi functions.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: @jasondavis Did you try with `trim($url)` as Ben suggested? For what it's worth your curl code works as expected in a loop locally.

Comment: @ben I actually have a much more complex version now that uses `curl_multi functions` and also runs the list in batches of X ammount at a time however it had the same problem, so I then tried your `trim()` idea, and I am shocked, it works now! This was driving me nuts, thanks so much, it's always the simple things.  If you would post all this as an answer I will except it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already covered in the question comments but it seems the problem would be extra spacing at the end of the url.

Calling `getRedirect(trim($url))` would fix it.

The space at the end is most likely turned into a querystring space (aka %20) and changes the value of query string parameters